# Count duplicate entries with a special condition in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates, rows, distinct-values

I am not new to MYSQL but I can't get my head around this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My tables are simplified for the example:

```
categories_table
+-----+  
| id  |  
+-----+  
|   1 |  
|   2 |  
|   3 |  
+-----+
```

```
links_table
+------+-------------+-------------------+
| id   | category_id | link              |
+------+-------------+-------------------+
| 1    |           1 | http://google.com |
| 2    |           2 | http://google.com |
| 3    |           2 | http://google.com |
| 4    |           5 | http://yahoo.com  |
| 5    |           1 | http://php.net    |
| 6    |           2 | http://php.net    |
+------+-------------+-------------------+
```

In *links table* I have thousands of rows (yes, **the same links connected to the same category**), and I would like to have a view table that lists the DISTINCT links, with the sum of DISTINCT categories a link is attached to. So in links_table id's 2 and 3 should only count once!

So in this example, the view table should look like this:

```
view
+-------------------+-------------------+
| sum_of_categories | link              |
+-------------------+-------------------+
| 2                 | http://google.com |
| 1                 | http://yahoo.com  |
| 2                 | http://php.net    |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: how did you get 2 in the view table for google? And do you mean count instead of sum?

Comment: Well, that's the tricky part, where I have stumbled. I needed the amount of distinct categories for a given link. In this example google is only attached to categories 1,2. So it means 2 for google.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select link, count( distinct category_id ) sum_of_categories
   from links_table
   group by link
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this works perfectly! I was about to write a reeealy complex subquery monster out of this...